# What is the usecase of Enum interface in Dart 2.14

Tags: dart

I was looking at the [changelogs](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of the Dart SDK and I noticed this in release notes for **Dart SDK v2.14**:

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation on this! Where can I use this? I tried to implement it but it didn't work!

Comment: You can add extension methods on all enums instead of needing to apply the extension methods on each specific enums.

Comment: Another use case, you can define generics to must extend from Enum, to make methods and classes that only takes enums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use-cases for the `Enum` super-interface for all `enum` declared types, which led to the interface being added were mainly a request for an ability to abstract over enums.

One of the most common requests was to extract the name from an enum.
Example:

```dart
enum FooBar {
 foo, bar;
}
```

People would ask for a way to get the string `"foo"` from the value `FooBar.foo`.
The name *is* available in the `toString`, which returns the string `"FooBar.foo"`, but is not otherwise accessible.

The common approach was to do

```dart
String enumName(dynamic value) {
  var string = enumValue.toString();
  return string.substring(string.indexOf('.') + 1);
}
```

You couldn't restrict the `value` to only enum values because there was no way to recognize enum values in the type system. That can now be written as

```dart
String enumName(Enum value) { ... }
```

instead, or as an extension:

```dart
extension EnumName on Enum {
  String get name => ....;
}
```

(The extension has the advantage that it doesn't prevent you from having an enum with a `name` member, say `enum PostalReceiver { name, address, zip, country; }`, which an instance member would).

Another example would be a copy of the Java `EnumSet`:

```dart
class EnumSet<T extends Enum> {
  int _bits = 0;
  final List<T> _values;
  EnumSet(List<T> values) : _values = values {
    if (values.length > 32) throw UnsupportedError("Too big");
  }
  void add(T value) {
    _bits |= 1 << value.index;
  }
  void remove(T value) {
    _bits &= ~(1 << value.index);
  }
  bool contains(T value) => _bits & (1 << value.index) != 0;
}
```

This can now be well typed, restricted to enums, and the `.index` operation is statically typed to return an `int`.
Without the `Enum` interface, there was no way to restrict to enums only, and no way to access `.index` except a dynamic call.

Enums are still restricted, you cannot implement the interface other than by creating an `enum`.